# Bigcommerce API customer custom field

Tags: api, bigcommerce

We are able to add custom field to Customer object - for example "Customer Number".

We would like to pull customer object using Bigcoomertce API by "Customer Number".

However, the API documentation does NOT show how to do this.

Is this possible and if yes - how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't an endpoint for custom fields on customers/addresses, only products. Hopefully they'll come out with this is a new version of their API though.

Comment: We now have an available GET request for custom fields on customers, but we don't yet have the POST/PUT functionality.